# Dropdown menu with incorrect size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a very simple dropdown menu with Twitter Bootstrap, basically a copy and paste from the [documentation examples as shown here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns).

But for some reason, the size of the dropdown menu (the `ul` element) is enough to fit just the first menu item. The screen shots can explain better:

Dropdown menu closed:

[image: Dropdown menu]

Dropdown menu open:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="userActions" data-toggle="dropdown">
        {{ App.userName }}
        <img id="configIcon" src="/Images/Project/Ícone_config.png">
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="userActions">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" target="_blank" href="/a">Gerenciamento</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" target="_blank" href="/UserProfile/EditPassword">Mudar senha</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sair</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The project uses Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript, it also includes AngularJS and jQuery. `<!DOCTYPE html>` is specified.

Why is the size wrong?

Comment: Need provide more detail on the CSS.

Comment: I've tested out your code and it works fine. Do you have any custom css that might be overwriting the default bootstrap behavior?

Comment: Yes, indeed I found a CSS selector which is also being applied to the dropdown menu: `#appHeader div.row * { height: inherit; }`. Needed an extra CSS containing `height: initial;` to fix it.Thanks for the tip.